# Can we host and angular/.Net Core application with shared hosting

Tags: hosting, shared-hosting, ovh, dedicated-hosting

WE have an angular/.net Core Application,
Wea want to delpoy it and we have this question,
Can we deploy it in a shared hosting or we need to use a dedicated hosting?.

If yes, we have already a domain but how can we transfer or place the build files?

Thanks.

Comment: You can run your .net core on shared hosting. I can't recommend Asphostportal highly enough, I've been with them for years to host .net website. If you already registered domain, you just need to point your domain to your hosting provider name server in order to host your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy a .NET application on OVH's shared hosting. Currently it only supports:

- PHP
- Python ([beta](https://labs.ovh.com/managed-nodejs))
- Ruby ([beta](https://labs.ovh.com/managed-ruby))
- Node.js ([beta](https://labs.ovh.com/managed-python))

However OVH starts to integrates [platform.sh](https://platform.sh/) on its servers: https://labs.ovh.com/web-paas-psh
And this solution [supports .NET](https://docs.platform.sh/languages/dotnet.html)
Note that this is still on OVH labs, meaning it is still in beta

Comment: Thanks for your response, the for an Anguler / .NEt Core application i need to use didicated hosting ?

Comment: What are you calling dedicated hosting ? Do you have a link to this OVH product page ? I can't find it

Comment: I wasn't clear maybe , for example from the choices in this link what should i shoose for an Angular / .Net Core application https://www.ovh.com/tn/order/webcloud/?hosting#/webCloud/hosting/select?selection=~()

Comment: As stated in my answers, all the offers displayed in your link ("Perso", "Pro", "Performance", "Cloud Web") are only supporting PHP.
The only solution at OVH currently to play with .NET is in lab/beta, and its here: https://labs.ovh.com/web-paas-psh